# How to access controller of a child directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I have a directive `FilePicker` that contains in its template an instance of the `Modal` directive, how can I get a reference to an instance of the `Modal` directive's controller from within the `FilePicker`'s controller?

I ask, of course, because I cannot find any way to do this, but this is a bitter disappointment in light of everything I've heard about directive controllers being the cornerstone of directive-to-directive communication rather than doing everything via `$scope`.

Comment: You can find the element inside the template and call controller().

Comment: Thanks @WalterBrand, that seems to be the only way. Shame it involves accessing the DOM, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of something in template? What? A template is just a simple string and that's all.
About controllers: 
DOM elements can be managed by angular controllers. Directives are being applied to DOM elements. Then can use controllers too. You can simply describe a directive controller by:

```
// directive with name parentDirective
{
    link: function () { ... },
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: [ '$scope', function ($scope) { 
      this.sayHello =  function () { alert('hello'); } 
      // 'this' references the instance of the directive controller and then can be required by a child 

    }],
    template: '<div><child-directive/></div>'

}

// child directive with the name childDirective
{
  require: '^parentDirective',
  link: function (scope, $element, attributes, parentDirectiveController) {
      parentDirectiveController.sayHello();
  }
}
```

Comment: This shows how to access a parent directive's controller from within a child directive, which is well documented, but not how to go the other way. It's how to go the other way that I was unsure about.

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice. Still you can search in a parent directive through DOM for the child directive DOM element, get its scope or data by $element.scope() or $element.data() and do whatever you want. Of course it can be done only after all that stuff is compiled and linked.